# How to send a cell (or records) range query to fetch a ranged feed from worksheet entry from iPhone app to Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: objective-c, optimization, gdata-api

I'm trying to find how to get a specified with range feed of cells (or 
records) from a worksheet entry.

I found that, there is a solution for that 
in ["Google Data APIs .NET client library"](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#cellsQueryExample)

and in ["Google Data API Python client library"](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#cellsQueryExample)

But can't find how to do it with objective-c. Is it possible? If yes, 
then how? 
If not, then how to  implement this opportunity & how hard is it to 
do? 
The reason i'm intrested is desire to reduce traffic among iPhone app 
& Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself while investigated Gdata-objectivec-client headers.
So the solution is to make a `GDataQuerySpreadsheet` to worksheet with entry with pre-set number of properties: `minimumRow, maximumRow, minimumColumn, maximumColumn`.
It is also possible to use simply - `(void)setRange:(NSString *)str;`

Here's a code example:

```
- (void) fetchWorksheet: (GDataEntryWorksheet*) worksheet {
    NSURL *cellsFeedURL = [[worksheet cellsLink] URL];
    if (cellsFeedURL) {
        GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
        GDataQuerySpreadsheet *query = [GDataQuerySpreadsheet spreadsheetQueryWithFeedURL: cellsFeedURL];
        [query setMinimumRow: 0];
        [query setMaximumRow: 2];
        [query setMinimumColumn: 0];
        [query setMaximumColumn: 2];
        [query setTitleQuery: @"myQuery"];

        ticket = [mService fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                                     delegate:self
                            didFinishSelector:@selector(fetchFeedOfCellsTicket:
                                                        finishedWithFeed:
                                                        error:)];
    }    
}
```

The only disadvantage of this is that resulting feed contains cells, but not records. And cells are considered deprecated (i've heard it). It would be better to fetch a table with records, and not worksheet with cells. But GData-objectivec-client doesn't support it, unfortunately.

But it works. I've checked.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide an Objective-C API to access spreadsheets. It is still possible to access the spreadsheets, but you will be responsible for creating the raw HTTP requests.

The NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection classes can be used to create and send the necessary HTTP requests. You'll definitely need a decent working knowledge of HTTP, but other than that it's hard to say just how difficult such an endeavor would be - it depends heavily on what your app allows the user to do. The more interactive and flexible it is, the more time you'll have to spend coding the individual requests.

For more info, you can look at the generalized version of the [GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#SendingCellQueries).

Other resources:
[NSURLRequest Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: There is an open source project that provide an Objective-C API to access google spreadsheets and other google services: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: I asked about optimization of work with an amount of worksheets and records in them, using gdata-objectivec-client.